# Dependency issue: sun-java6-jdk (bindiff)

Tags: linux, dependencies, java-6, ubuntu-12.10

I am trying to install bindiff. When I try to install through archive manager I am welcomed by the following message "Dependency is not satisfiable: sun-java6-jre". (I am running ubuntu 12.10)

I have tried adding a repository

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ lucid partner"
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ferramroberto/java
```

This did not work.

I also currently have java 7 installed, and have done sudo apt-get update

I tried "sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jdk" and I receive the following:

sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jdk Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done Package sun-java6-jdk is not available, but is referred to by another package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source

E: Package 'sun-java6-jdk' has no installation candidate

SOLVED:
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get remove java-common
sudo apt-get install oracle-java6-installer
sudo apt-get purge java common

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following terminal commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get remove java-common 
sudo apt-get install oracle-java6-installer
sudo apt-get purge java common
```